# how to generate my medical record to CCR and CCD file?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to generate some medical records to CCR and CCD files. I have no idea to handle this. Is there any .net liberary to do this? thank you so much.

Comment: You'll have to give a lot more information to get an answer.

Comment: CCR and CCD are kinds of standard to exchange medical record. and now i need to generated all the records to these two kinds of xml file. so i want to know anybody had do this and how they solved it?

Comment: You've made clear that the output should be CCR/CCD.  What is the input? Plain ole' paper files?  XML? CSV? other?

Comment: the input is the data retrieved from database, and the output should be CCR/CCD format's xml file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've generated CCR records in much the same way as you'd generate any XML using both [XMLDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) and a file based template system using field substitution.

The Medical Business Intelligence has an entry [Creating C# Bindings for CCR and CCD](http://medbi.blogspot.com/2008/02/creating-c-bindings-for-ccr-and-ccd.html)

Also Google Data / Google health has CCR in their [C# health sample](http://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/source/browse/#svn/trunk/clients/cs/src/ghealth) which may be useful.

Comment: thx Richard, it is great use for me, thanks a lot.